# Shelosha Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-three?

### ?שלשה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 323.

When 'ג' is the first letter of the numerological technique you'd like to apply lazily, try something else.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred twenty-two entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: We are all eagerly awaiting your disseminating the question about 324. That is, the [_chai_-squared distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45826/5323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ezra 2:17

בני בצי שלש מאות עשרים ושלשה

although in Nechemia 7:23 it says

בני בצי שלש מאות עשרים וארבעה

Comment: Well there you go ruining your answer for 324

Comment: @YEZ: I have something else lined up.