# Arba'a Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-four?

### ?ארבעה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 324? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 324, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

While lazy gematria might find you a match, it's unlikely to be a high-quality one.

Comment: Attempting a new formula, aiming for full SE-compliance. Does this post achieve that, in your opinion?

Comment: "Echad mi yodeya implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance...for each natural number" - really?

Comment: @Ypnypn, it seems to me to be a reasonable inference from the song. Otherwise, why ask those questions?

Comment: By the time your seder is finished, it should be about time to say shema on the *next* morning!

Comment: @IsaacMoses, re your first comment: yes.

Comment: @IsaacMoses See some of the answers at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/857/why-do-we-sing-echad-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 11, accepted):

324 was the number of men present at the meal with the three angels who visited Avrohom - Avrohom, Yishmael, Eliezer, the three angels, and the 318 trained men of Avrohom that are mentioned in [Bereishis 14:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209#v=14), as discussed in this [post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/why-did-abraham-treat-his-three-visitors-in-this-way/45832#45832).

Comment: I will argue that you can only count either Eliezer or 318 based on that medrash. You substitute Sarah and count all present to keep the cheshbon.

Answer (score 4):

Per the Qetoret recipe laid out in Masekhet Keritot ([6A](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=6&format=text)), there are 324 *maneh* in a few different combinations of samanim (spices).

The first four samanim in the Qetoret comprise 280 *maneh*: Tzori (70), Tzipporen (70), Helbenah (70), Levonah (70). The remaining 44 *maneh* can be comprised of any of the following combinations of samanim:

- Mor (16), Qetzi'ah (16), Qoshet (12)
- Mor (16), Qetzi'ah (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)
- Mor (16), Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Qoshet (12)
- Mor (16), Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)
- Mor (16), Kharkhom (16), Qoshet (12)
- Mor (16), Kharkhom (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)
- Qetzi'ah (16), Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Qoshet (12)
- Qetzi'ah (16), Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)
- Qetzi'ah (16), Kharkhom (16), Qoshet (12)
- Qetzi'ah (16), Kharkhom (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)
- Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Kharkom (16), Qoshet (12)
- Shibbolet Nehrd (16), Kharkom (16), Qilufah (3), Qinnamon (9)

HaRav Zamir Kohen, citing the Zohar HaQadosh, said that the Qetoret (and reading Pitum HaQetoret) served/serves as a tremendous defense against the forces of evil. Just as RaSh"I ([Shemot 30:34](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9891/jewish/Chapter-30.htm#v=34&showrashi=true)) states that Helbenah symbolizes "Posh'ei Yisra'el", I think it is likely (though I do not have a source for it), that each and every spice has distinct literal/Qabbalistic significance. If so, their combinations would also yield distinct literal/Qabbalistic significance.

Comment: -1 on your -1, because RaSh"I comments on the Helbenah, not to imply H"W that only the Helbenah was brought as Qetoret offering, but to interpret the inclusion of the Helbenah itself. Similarly, different combinations may have different meanings (although, again, I don't have a source for such a proposition). For example, perhaps knowing that Mor, Qetzi'ah and Qoshet (along with the four 70 *maneh* samanim) make up 324 *maneh* tells us what those Jews' missions are together/separately within Kelal Yisra'el.

Answer (score 3):

It is the amount which is mentioned in a [letter by the Friediker Rebbi Zatzal](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31683&st=&pgnum=641&hilite=) in the year 5705 which was donated anonymously for the Bikur Cholim of Lubavitch.

Perhaps the reason of this donation amount is due to 18 x 18 = 324 (See [Source for # times chai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/source-for-times-chai))

Comment: Is a random one time donation in 5705 really that significant to Judaism?

Answer (score 3):

[Nechemiah 7:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Nehemiah.7.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> בְּנֵ֣י בֵצָ֔י שְׁלֹ֥שׁ מֵא֖וֹת עֶשְׂרִ֥ים וְאַרְבָּעָֽה׃ (ס)
>
> The sons of Bezai—324

Answer (score -2):

Gematria of 'vayivarech elohim', 'vayitzav elohim es ha'adam', 'vayomer habet na', 'Vayar v'hineh ayil' - I think this is most important.

Comment: Why are any of these important?